# Where can I create a directory without Administrator Rights / Privileges?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am creating a DLL that goes with a 3rd-party program. Whether or not the 3rd-party program has Administrator rights in Windows is outside my control.

The DLL needs to create a directory, but it seems like CreateDirectory won't work because it doesn't have administrator rights.

Escalating the UAC isn't an option because I am only modifying the DLL, not the 3rd-party program. I can't force the user to right-click the 3rd-party program and "Run As Administrator".

*(Visual C++ 2010)*

**EDIT**

I am trying to write to `C:\ProgramData\`. I retrieve that path using `SHGetFolderPath()` and `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`.

Comment: `%APPDATA%` seems most likely given the lack of information. (http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)

Comment: That's strange: on my 32-bit W7, %ProgramData% points to a hidden "C:\ProgramData" with no spaces.  I can create the a directory in it using both _mkdir and CreateDirectory as a non-admin user.  Does "C:\Program Data" exist?  As a non-admin user, you can't write to the C: drive.

Comment: @cup I removed the space. That's what I meant. Please teach me, how did you test being a non-admin user?

Comment: Create a non admin user.  Login as that user or runas that user (you have to set a password for the latter). Write a program which creates a directory inside %ProgramData%.

Comment: Generally speaking, without administrator privileges, you can only write to locations for the current user, not to common locations.  If you need a common area that users can write to, you need a privileged installer to create a subdirectory in the common area and explicitly set the ACL to grant users write access.  (This is a simplified explanation, but it suits the most common situations.)

Answer (score 5):

Use `CSIDL_APPDATA` as the *root* folder for any user-specific directories/files, otherwise use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` instead.  Either way, create your own subfolder under the chosen *root* for your app/DLL, as the *root* folder itself is protected from being written to.  Typically, an installer should create your subfolder with adequate rights, and then the app/DLL can access it as needed.

Comment: I tried this. The installer creates a directory under C:\ProgramData using CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, but the DLL still does not create any text files in the new directory.

Comment: Does the installer adjust the security rights of your subfolder to allow users to write to it? It is not enough to just create the folder. Doing so will inherit the restricted rights of its parent folder, so the installer has to set desired security while/after creating it. That is why this solution involves an installer in the first place, since an installer should run as an admin so it can do things like write to restricted folders and change security rights.

Answer (score 1):

Read the `TEMP` environment variable, and use the result to create temporary files and/or directories. Use `APPDATA` for persistent ones.

Please note that at least `APPDATA` is user specific.